# My system became suddenly read-only

Tags: filesystems, linux-mint, read-only

System Linux Mint 17 x64.

My local FS suddenly became read-only, I had to restart.

Why could this happen?

Could I fix it without restart?

[syslog file](https://pastebin.com/QrK9zPMR)

Comment: Did you check `dmesg`? `syslog`? anything? Do you want us to guess why your *particular* filesystem became read-only? Or do you want to know every possible reason for *any* filesystem to become read-only?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm a noob, didn't think / know that. But after your comment, I now know more. Added log in question above.

Comment: Note that most of the time, root is configured to remount in readonly mode (`errors=remount-ro`). if an error occurs. as for what that error was, go to /var/log, and look at the dmesg log, syslog, etc for pertinent messages at about the time the issue occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the system became read-only is that I was trying to mount a problematic ntfs partition, which, on fail, made the local fs become read-only, probably for security / integrity reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem on my computer for over 1 year and tried everything to solve the problem. Suddenly Linux goes into read-only mode. If you are editing something you are unable to save and have to execute `fsck` command and reset the computer. The computer is also very slow and freezing all the time. I removed the dual boot and left only Ubuntu, upgraded Ubuntu from version 18.04 LTS to version 20.04 LTS, and it didn't work. What was crucial to solving the problem is the use of the `dmesg` command. The experience didn't work out for me, just this command. The function of this command is to monitor the computer.

In my case, the problem was related to the SSD incompatibility with Ubuntu. I used HDD and after I switched to SSD the problem came up. The problem was solved by **updating the SSD firmware**, which was only possible by partitioned Windowns, because Kingston does not have the program to update firmware through Linux. I also installed the dual boot Windowns and Linux, first installing Windows over the entire SSD, then deallocating space through Windowns and installing Ubuntu,  but it is very unlikely that this was the solution to the problem.